# Why is Assert.AreEqual failing in NUnit?

Tags: nunit, assert

"Robert" exists in the NWind database. The following C# code fails in NUnit:

```
public void Robert_exists()
{
    EmployeeBO empl = new EmployeeBO();
    Boolean result = empl.DoesEmployeeRecordExists("Robert"); 
    Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
}
```

But single stepping shows that "result" is "true"

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If it is debugging that result is true, then this should work. However, as a test, you can try using the `Assert.IsTrue(result);` method?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that just now. It failed. To test NUnit, I tried Boolean result = true;
//Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
Assert.IsTrue(result); Both of these asserts work. BTW: I'm using MS Visual Web Developer Express, and the debugger clearly shows "true" for the returned value of "result". Note also that MBUnit fails when NUnit fails.